# "Flag the Moderator" flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderators

I think it would be an interesting idea for the regular users to have the ability to flag the moderator if he/she feels that a moderator's decision was inappropriate.
It would be like a "Throw out the moderator vote."  It may give that so desired push back everyone is looking for.  Perhaps after a certain threshold of such votes, that moderator will be temporarily dethroned or penalized.

Think of it like a congressional impeachment by **the people**, in a proper checks and balances system.

Regarding, whether Moderators listen, i've (the owner of this question) just flagged this question to be deleted. "This question is not liked, deemed invalid in quality, by a large proportional majority of votes."  Let's see how well the moderators listen.

Comment: discussed in depth at MSE, see eg [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges) and [Handling Calls to Remove a Moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator)

Comment: Is it inappropriate for me to downvote this?  Seriously though, the best way to get the attention of a moderator is to flag a post. The second best way to get attention if you think a moderator has overstepped their bounds is to flag a post a moderator has acted on. Third best way is to bring the issue to meta.

Comment: @George, I'm looking for a more democratic approach in numbers and loud voice, rather than one single ignored shout.

Comment: Are you talking about a diamond moderator or the community @Pinch? Either way flag a post and ask a diamond moderator to deal with it. If it's not sorted to your satisfaction then _politely_ raise a request on meta/talk to the team.

Comment: @gnat I am aware of the issue and that small bone thrown, now looking for a solution.

Comment: @Pinch How is bringing the issue to meta not democratic enough for you?

Comment: @Pinch: what makes you feel that a single shout is ignored?

Comment: @Pinch there is no way for readers of your question to find out that you are aware of that and that it differs; consider [edit]ing it to clarify this

Comment: Judging by your most recent edits [What form of government does StackExchange resemble?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/320/1680) on politics.SE is related.

Comment: Do you have a proposed system for implementing a "Throw out the moderator vote"? Would there be a "don't throw out the moderator" vote? Have you considered [voluntary response bias](http://stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=voluntary_response_bias)?

Comment: A "don't throw out the moderator vote"? Let's focus on stuff we'll actually use @0x7fffffff. ;)

Comment: Put it on meta if you don't agree with the moderator, and ask for better explanations.

Answer (score 26):

You can already do this.  If you feel a moderator acted inappropriately on a post, flag it and explain why you think they acted inappropriately and the action will be reviewed.

If you would like to have a more involved discussion of the topic, or you feel that the response to such a flag is not satisfactory for you, then come to meta.  Post a question in which you describe the moderation action you have observed, and explain why you think it is improper.  This will either result in an explanation of why the moderation action was correct, or it'll result in its reversal.

Comment: I'm looking for a more democratic approach in numbers and loud voice, rather than one single ignored shout.

Comment: @Pinch And how does having a meta post *not* accomplish exactly that?  If the community at large feels that your assertion that the moderation action was improper, they can provide that feedback on a meta question.  When a moderator clearly sees that the community feels their action was improper, the action will be reversed.

Comment: @Pinch: what makes you think your lone voice goes unheard? Your post here on Meta is certainly getting attention, for example.

Comment: And if you really wanted to take the issue higher up, you could always email the team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of each site.

Answer (score 17):

There are checks and balances on moderator power already, but they are not as simple and rigid as the system you proposed. There are two major ways to challenge moderator decisions:

- Make a post on the appropriate meta to challenge the moderator decision
- Write a mail to team@stackexchange.com or use the "contact us" link in the footer

Both have one thing in common, you have to do more than just press a button. You have to convince the community or the SE team why the moderator action was inappropriate.