# Why was my question about a difference in behavior between .NET 4.7.1 and .NET 6 poorly received?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, voting

I recently got question banned and as a result I am very careful when writing a question. Today, I was once again downvoted when asking what I felt was a solid, well written [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556199/entrypointnotfoundexception-when-using-net-6-0-resolved-by-using-4-7-1).

As I have learned in my research trying to understand Stack Overflow's requirements, [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has the following attributes:

- A well written title ✅
- Shows adequate research ✅
- Introduces the problem before any code ✅
- Helps others reproduce the problem ✅
- Is well written, clear and understandable ✅
- Has all the relevant tags ✅

I feel like the question I asked meets all of these criteria. Therefore, I do not understand why it was downvoted and poorly received.

This is why people are very [frustrated with this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399848/downvotes-research-why-do-we-need-that) in the community. We follow the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do hours of research, and when we reach out with a thoughtful and well written question, we still get downvoted and eventually question banned.

Is there something I am doing wrong in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556199/entrypointnotfoundexception-when-using-net-6-0-resolved-by-using-4-7-1)?

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me why you think you should replace the question with another one like you did in the linked post. You're supposed to _improve_ existing questions, not replace it with other ones to circumvent a question ban.

Comment: Personally, I don't really see the harm in replacing an old question that had no comments, votes, or answers.  I wouldn't do anything to stop someone from doing that.  That said, I suspect that's the reason for the downvotes - many people don't like that.

Comment: Otherwise, I don't see anything immediately apparent that's wrong with it - but I'm not a subject matter expert.  It is possible that there's something apparent to subject matter experts that is wrong with it.

Comment: Please consider not rage quitting. For instance, ***log out*** of Stack Overflow and take a [wikiholiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikibreak) of, say, two or three weeks. And think about the ***design decisions*** for an alternative to Stack Overflow (for instance, to not repeat the exact same mistakes, like not designing for [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) (which Stack Overflow has been in for nearly 12 years now)).

Answer (score 17):

As someone with some .NET knowledge (admittedly very stale these days, but not entirely forgotten), as well as someone with a *lot* of experience assessing the quality of questions, I reviewed [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66556199). It is fine. Neither I nor another moderator that I discussed this with can find any reason why it, in its *current form*, was downvoted.

It does appear that you had originally asked a completely different question, then edited it into the current form. That's technically a rule violation. While we do encourage users to edit their questions and improve them, we stop short of allowing people to submit edits that completely change the question into something different. However, in this case, since there had been no interaction whatsoever from the community (no answers, no comments, and not even any votes at the time you submitted your edit), it's hard to get too upset about this minor offense.

I've made some minor polishing edits to your question and undeleted it. As noted, there is nothing wrong with it in its current form.

I, personally, find the "research" section to be noisy and pointless. There is no reason to share links to things you found that are entirely unrelated and unhelpful, and presenting them as a laundry list is just, well, off-putting and noisy. But that's a personal stylistic thing, and barely a reason to downvote, if even. I would recommend not including this type of thing in future questions; it doesn't help anyone to understand the problem or provide a good answer.

---

Now, that question aside, your interactions here on this Meta post have been rather problematic. You make a lot of claims that are simply untrue, and imply a very entitled attitude. You claim things like *"I deserve a fresh start"*, but don't bother to tell us why. Why do you deserve this? You claim that *"I am just looking for some fairness, which there clearly isn't any of"*, but that is demonstratively untrue; you're actually looking for special treatment, special in the sense that it is different than the kind of treatment that other users receive.

I've deleted those comments, and the replies to them, because they are not constructive and, more importantly, because they are not germane to what you are asking here in this specific question, which is for advice/feedback on a specific question on the main Stack Overflow site—a perfectly valid *and commendable* use of Meta.

I don't really want to get into litigating the site's policies and restrictions, because I'm tired of having this discussion over and over, and it's unlikely to do any good to have it again. But I do want to be *very clear* that creating a new account as a way of bypassing restrictions applied to your current account is considered an abuse of the system. It is not allowed, and action will be taken by moderators, including restricting the ability of subsequent accounts to interact with the site (in order to match or even exceed the restrictions applied to the original/main account). So, please don't do this.

If you'd like to work with us to understand the issues, or even determine that there are not any and a mistake was made in how some of your content was handled, that's fine. Mistakes do happen, and, more often, differences in judgment happen. People here are quite happy to work with you to help you improve your content, because our goal is really to improve the *overall* quality of content on the site. But when you start calling us "toxic", well, that doesn't motivate anyone to want to help you. That motivates us to get you to stop hurling accusations.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that was why I did. I posted it and then a few minutes later I realized it was not a good question and deleted it. 
At the time I thought deleted questions were just gone. 

I know better now. 

I Know right?? I did not want to put the research section either, but someone mentioned that it was likely getting several down votes because I didnt supply research. I thought It was kind of self explainatory... but with 4 downvotes... 

Anyway, I don't think I can use stack over flow anymore. I am brought to tears because every time I reach out for help I end up with downvotes.

Comment: I think we really need a website that cares about helping people with their code, and so I just bought a website and I am going to build it. 
I hope that I can make something good, that will help people, because its clear that I as a developer, I am developing questions improperly and its stopping me from moving forward with my problems.

Comment: I understand how it can be frustrating to receive downvotes on something where you've actually taken the time to put in effort, but please understand that downvotes are not meant to be personal attacks, so you really shouldn't take them personally. 4 downvotes means that 4 random people on the Internet didn't like what you posted or didn't think it was good enough. It is my firm belief that that should not be enough to bring you to tears.

Comment: But they are personal attacks cody. Downvotes lead to a disconnection from a community we need to help us grow.

Comment: I have a question ban, I am developer and good one. I need to be able to connect with my peers, and when it becomes about stylization over content, (which I agree needs moderation, but not to the extent that people can no longer participate), then we are left helpless, needing a solution. There is clearly a need for a community that can accept questions, without banning people when they arent perfect.

I am going to make that community. And I hope, I just hope, that others will be helped by it, and not left feeling helpless when they need help, like I do here.

Comment: And I know I am not alone on this :(

Comment: Downvotes are not personal attacks any more than upvotes are personal... whatever the opposite of an attack is. Upvotes are a sign of agreement and approval; they suggest that the content is useful, clear, and a valuable contribution to Stack Overflow's knowledge base. Downvotes are the opposite. You should not be looking to this website (or probably any other, but *definitely* not this one) to provide for your personal growth or personal connections. That's not what this site is for. SO is like Wikipedia, except that it's in the form of bite-sized questions and answers, not long-form articles

Comment: I am not looking for personal connections Cody, nor have I anywhere Implied that. And this website is absolutely for personal growth. Any time you gain knowledge, you grow. 
When you ask a question, and you receive a valid answer, you grow. Your knowledge expands.

Comment: *"I need to be able to connect with my peers,"* is where you implied it, I read it the same way as Cody appears to have, even if that wasn't your intention.

Comment: I agree that the negative reception of your question was puzzling and, I think, unjustified. But drawing broader conclusions from that just doesn't follow. Getting a question downvoted doesn't mean you're a bad developer. I have had, and still continue to get, questions downvoted that I don't think have obvious quality issues (see, for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55769904)). It isn't a commentary on me as a person or a developer. You said "I need to be able to connect with my peers"…how is that not looking for a personal connection?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the use of the word community. We here are a community, and as developers, we depend on each other to help each other grow, through the sharing of knowledge through questions and answers. This makes us a community.

Comment: We are *not* here as a community. We are here as individuals contributing to a knowledge base. As stated in the [tour], we are trying to build a high-quality library of answers to questions about programming. What you seem to be searching for is a social network for developers. While that might be valuable (I'm personally not interested), it *definitely* isn't what Stack Overflow is or is meant to be. You can certainly learn things from this site, and those things might help you grow as a person and/or a developer, but that's not the site's mission.

Comment: Peers means People in the same field of work
Connect means to discuss, debate or share knowledge. 
Connecting with my peers just means to communicate with like-minded people

Comment: This is not a site for that, any more than a museum is a site for archaeologists to connect with their peers or a library is a place for pet-lovers to connect with other pet lovers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/ Go to the homepage of stack overflow.
In the title you will see
StackOverflow - Where developers Learn, Share, and Build careers.
That is the definition of a community.

Comment: Learning and sharing refers to reading, researching, asking and answering questions. Build careers is about Jobs... which is effectively dead. A community, but not a "community".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives Where stackoverflow explicitly tries to promote community growth.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of misinformation that the marketing department has placed on the home page. I've complained about that numerous times before. It is doing a severe disservice by improperly setting users' expectations. You appear to have been the latest victim. The fact that the people who come to this site are developers is merely coincidental, as is the fact that by contributing to this knowledge base, we share information with each other. This is *not* a social networking site. It is *not* a community. It is a Q&A site. If you want community, you should look elsewhere from here.

Comment: Its not misinformation, its misinterpretation. 
You think that I want something other than to ask questions and get answers, when I was just being elegant in the way that I was communicating, by wording it in a way that is elegant.

Comment: Collectives also FWIW are nothing to do with community, they're just groups of related tags bundled together and "owned" by some sponsor. Merely a filing cabinet of sorts.

Comment: In my city, this is how we talk, and I would appreciate it if you would refrain from putting words in my mouth.

Comment: Anyways, this is misuse of comments. Comments are not for debating philosophy nor for splitting hairs.

Comment: When you're talking with people internationally you need to understand that not everybody will talk the same way as you, nor interpret things the way you necessarily intend them to. You certainly shouldn't assume malice or people "putting words in your mouth" simply because they're reading something differently to how you expected. Don't try to be elegant, try to be clear.

Comment: What you call "elegant" is what I call "misleading". It sets expectations that this is some kind of community where people care about other people. It isn't; we don't. This is strictly a question and answer site; the only things we care about are questions and answers (i.e., content). By using flowery language to describe some *potential consequences* of contributing here, it does a very real disservice to new users who don't properly understand our model by creating improper expectations. This, in turn, leads to a lot of frustration when such new users start receiving downvotes.

Comment: This chit chat here, this exchange of information... This is community. This is discussion, that breeds a better understanding. 
If you dont understand that, then now you do. This IS community. Responding is community. You are chatting, discussing, debating. Its a community. Regardless of whether you want to call it that.

Comment: This is the Meta site. Discussion and exchange of information is what we do here, in order to help support the people who are trying to use the main site. What we are doing here would be completely inappropriate on the main Stack Overflow site. That's why Meta was created. I am, as a moderator, willing to help you to the best of my ability, both to understand how SO was meant to work and to help you figure out how to benefit from it, b/c I do think it's an amazing resource. Meta works very much like a support/help desk. The main site isn't like that; treating it that way will turn out poorly.

Comment: @Triangle4 Re: misinformation, yes, it's misinformation and misleading. The community (read: the core users and ex-staff who really care about SO) has put their thoughts on here: [Revisiting our logged-out homepage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406051/2821954). See how they were against this forced change.

Comment: It is the meta site, and yet I challenge you to find one stackoverflow post where people don't dicsuss like a community in the comments. Additionally you yourself called it a forum. 
The Websters Dictionary Definition of a forum is https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forum exactly what I am saying. 

And thirdly, there is nothing in these comments that would indicate that anyone has a difficulty understanding the English language. Everyone here is clearly capable of conveying ideas and concepts in english. 

So what you are demonstrating, is a desire to attack everything I say.

Comment: I just have to reiterate, that community is what it is. It does not matter whether you personal agree with the definition of it, anymore than if you disagree that we need oxygen to breathe. 

Community is what it is. And stack overflow, regardless of what fancy term someone wants to attribute to it, is a community. We all discuss and share information.

Comment: Stackoverflow exists as a part of a major community. We are a community of developers, NOT THOSE OF US ON STACK OVERFLOW, all developers in the world are a community. We talk about science, we refer to it as the scientific community. In the workplace, when we talk about computer science, we refer to it as a the community. We. Are. The community. All of us. 

Stackoverflow exists, whether by intention or not, to serve that community as a library of questions and answers. As a side effect, the medium for precipitating that communication is other members of that community.

Comment: My question, helped that community, and down voting it for petty reasons as outlined above, is poor stewardship of said information. Period. 
Like me or not, that question needs an answer. And its selfish of anyone to deprive future answer seekers the opportunity to find that answer. That is why stackoverflow exists. 
So politics should not stand in the way of successfully completing the mission of stackoverflow. 
I am reading this back and am blown away, because I am upset with how I my question was received, and yet I am defending the very foundation of what stackoverflow stands for.

Comment: @Triangle4 Forums are for _open discussion or expression_. The only place true open discussion can occur here is in chat, not on SO itself. And expression is poorly defined. Thus, not a forum by the definition you've given. SO is only a community by definition in that we share a common interest (programming) but it's not possible to "be part of the community" that you appear to want it to be as _that_ form of community doesn't exist here. Hence why I said above that it's a community, but not a "community". SO _isn't_ what you appear to want it to be.

Comment: Again nick, you are splitting hairs. Missing the point. You disputing because you don't have an answer to the question and want someone to argue with. I have said my piece. I have initiated the deletion of my account, and this time tomorrow, you are all on your own. 

Have a good night :)

Comment: @Triangle4 `I challenge you to find one stackoverflow post where people don't dicsuss like a community in the comments` Find one post on SO where this is true, and it won't be longer after that.  Discussions like that are, for good reason, usually deleted or moved to chat.  Discussions of that kind are not allowed on the main site.

Comment: Our semantic disagreements aside, we will not be permitting you to delete your account, given that your expressed intention is to start over again with another account. As noted in my answer, that is breaking the rules on this site, and it is the job of moderators not to allow that.

Comment: @Triangle4 If I'm missing your point, you're clearly not doing a good job of explaining it because all I see is someone trying to fit SO into a box and trying to tell others what it's meant to be without actually knowing what it's meant to be...

Comment: Well Cody, be that as it may, I already said that I wasn't creating a new account as I was informed it was not allowed. 
And Its the law in canada, you cannot retain my information if I ask for it to be deleted. 

And thirdly, how does preventing me from creating an account stop me from using another email? I fail to see what your plan is here other than upsetting me. Which you are clearly trying to do.

Comment: I have no intention of upsetting you, but merely to enforce the rules of this platform, which remain true regardless of which country you are accessing the site from. If you seek to be forgotten, you wouldn't be creating a new account. If you don't want to create a new account, then you have no need of deleting this one, so there's no further action that needs to be taken. Best wishes to you.

Comment: You are right I come across entitled. I apologize for that. I don't deserve another chance. My questions are garbage.
You are right, If you are missing the point it must be my fault. I am going to have to work on improving myself a bit I guess. 
If this many people disagree with me, I realize it must be me that is the issue. So I will remove my comments and apologize for offending anyone... I guess its not a community, which I acknowledge now, so I dont need to apologize. 
So  many things to consider.

Comment: Cody, this is why I am upset. I keep saying something and you are missing it. I already said I have no intent of creating a new account. Long before you told me you were going to block the delete.

Comment: And you know what, I think I have been doing that too. We all read things too quickly and miss the authors intent.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts.
I apologize for reopening a deleted question. I Searched policy before doing so and did not find a reason why I could not, which is why I did it. 

After I found out it was against policy I deleted it and someone reopened it. 

I am trying to do a good job here, and get an answer. That's all I want. Just an answer. Not a community. I just want answers when I have a problem. 

I am sorry for offending you all, I never intended to. I clearly need to work on myself, and so I will do that. 

Thank you all for the time you invested in this. 
Cheers.

Comment: I just wanted to say one last thing.
If were not a community, we should really remove the terminology from community on the site. I mean I just got ripped a new one for calling stack a community... and yet:
https://ibb.co/80RfD4f This picture shows that when we change our profile, its called a community, by the developers who made it. 

So if we want people like me to stop treating it that way, can we please stop calling it that throughout the site?

Comment: And I am not trying to be rude by writing that, I hope you dont take it that way. I am saying it as nicely as I can and as well meaning as I can. :)

Comment: @Andrew stands with Ukraine: It doesn't say that. It says *"Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers"*. What is up with the insistence on misspelling [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)?

Comment: @Andrew stands with Ukraine: Re *"I just bought a website"*: That sounds exciting. Breaking new ground is due (and not just cloning the known). What is the domain? Where can we follow the progress, incl. the design decisions (e.g., it is easy to fall into the forum trap and not design for [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September))? On [Discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_%28software%29)? Twitter? A blog? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Comment: I considered sharing it as proof. But I am not sure I trust anyone here.https://ibb.co/YTyTDbL There is the proof. I would never want the kind of negativity I experienced here, on there, so not interested in anyone here joining. You can, I am sure I wont know about it. But I am certainly not inviting the risk of a boycott, or anything by sharing its name and linking it to this nonsense post, where my words have bee  twisted and CoC has been violated to make an example of me. The kind of people that do that, will not be guiding or helping me.

Comment: @AndrewstandswithUkraine This place is a community. But it's not a community in which *you* have defined it. We come together but our goal is not to seek approval/appraisal from our peers, as CodyGray and others have said. SE is a collection of Q&A sites and we gather around a vested interest in providing *high-quality Q&A* in the communities whose topics interest us. Curation and quality activities are what this place is centered around. The fact that the topic of SO itself is programming is incidental.

Comment: I understand it can be frustrating when personal expectations of this place aren't met, and I get that (and was on your side of the fence once, too). But this isn't a place where upvotes mean you are a competent programmer just as downvotes don't mean you are incompetent. We're not here to provide support for each other (although sometimes major community backlash can result in that effect). There are many other communities on other sites that offer what you are seeking, approval and support from your peers. SO simply is not that place, and is why it can sometimes come across as cold and blunt

Comment: Negative and positive feedback should not be taken personally on the main site; we focus on the *content*, not the *user*.

Comment: I dont see where I have defined it as anythibg other than a place to ask questions and rexieve answers. It was written above that I defined it as a place to connect with my peers, however someone deleted that, which was miscontrued.

Comment: Bender, how is it not personal when someone rips me apart in their answer? I am not sure what he/they was/were referring to either. Someone made an accusation and I responded in kind. And he/they felt I was entitled, called me out on CoC and yet put such information in his Answer. How is that any better than me calling something toxic? Which that kind of behaviour is, calling me entitled is personal. Doing it in an answer is a CoC violation.

Comment: If you're referring to *this* answer, we're on meta. Cody Gray is a mod and called out behavior, which is acceptable here as it is in direct response to points in your question and behavior on this post. Discussing the meta-aspect of questions, answers, and user behaviors are significantly on topic for meta-discussions. If you're referring to an answer to one of your questions on the main site, can you provide an example?

Comment: So stack allows personal attacks on meta? then why did they delete my comment when I said someone was being toxic? I am so confused.

Comment: What are you identifying as a personal attack? Nothing I've read makes assumptions about you, only uses what is publicly available about your behavior. *Blunt*, perhaps, but nothing I would consider a "personal attack" myself. I am not a mod, so I can't speak to any comments which were deleted as normal users can't read deleted comments no matter how much rep we have.

Comment: @AndrewstandswithUkraine If you feel a moderator has acted in bad faith (I don't feel anyone here has done so however), you have some options outlined in the [answers to this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251866/584676).

Comment: "That's technically a rule violation" why are you deleting my comment telling you that that's not a rule violation, and not only that, it's worse, since such a "rule" would go against the principle that everything can be improved on the site, up to and including your own post? There's no rule violation in any action of the user, technical or not.

Comment: @Braiam "Improving" requires that something of the original remains. You can't improve a house by tearing it down, removing the foundation, all plumbing and wiring connections from the outside, and starting over. That's "building a new house", not "improving the old house".

Comment: @HereticMonkey no, improving means that it's better than what it was. If it's required to be totally remade from the ground up, that's still improving. It's called total re-engineering. Restricting "improvements" to only those actions that keep something is one of the many shortcomings that many organizations have. Heck, if you don't do that you will be stuck with legacy systems that kinda-but-not-sorta work and you only try to patch it up to keep it going. If you ever had to deal with such system, that's what this "rule" is about.

Comment: If you want to start a philosophical discussion about the Ship of Theseus or bacterial replication, please do so as a new Q&A, not in the already *ridiculously long* comment thread here. Heretic Monkey has adequately summarized the standard policy, which is that you're welcome to improve things, even *drastically*, so long as you don't simply delete and replace them with something new. If you want to delete things, well, there's a button for that, and it isn't labeled "edit". @Braiam

Comment: I didn't say delete. But if my question is unclear or too broad and I reformulate it, that's called edit. I do not need to remove it. Also, policy can be clear and wrong. That policy goes against the actual policy of "Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it". I'm not discussing Theseus ship, I'm discussing backwards policy that de-naturalize the essence of the site. But apparently, [moderators aren't ready for that conversation yet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418169/#comment911280_418192)

Answer (score 3):

I think that there are two main reasons here. One is that you say that you've scoured the internet, but you don't actually include anything specific that you've done - this makes it harder for others to suggest things to try, because they don't know what *specifically* you've tried. The second reason is that you name the error, but don't give much more detail - it could also help to say something such as how this answer does it: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918621/python-argparse-namespace-error#:~:text=Traceback%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918621/python-argparse-namespace-error#:%7E:text=Traceback%20).

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72336750/pull-to-refresh-using-scrollview-in-swiftui#comment127815499_72336750. This shows certain approaches that the OP has taken. I would also suggest doing something like this: "I have tried example.com/tutorial, but that didn't work because that was referencing a depreciated version of the framework I'm using." Describe a few sources that you have seen and why they didn't work - that will also help others because it will reduce the chances of an answer that has already been tried.

Comment: That’s an entirely different question. It’s also a different author so finding it difficult to see the connection?

Comment: The original comment by the OP was deleted - they were asking how to show what they had tried. My comment above was an example. Their comment was deleted because their account was deleted.

Answer (score -3):

You know what, I don't see it [in the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66556199/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries). The question was deleted two minutes after it was asked and didn't get any vote (close, up, down) until well after you edited it, unless the timeline lies and the votes occurred before the edit (in which case that seems to be a bug). It seems that it isn't that poorly received, it may be controversial, but not poorly received.